# Terraform import on aws_s3_bucket asking me both acl=private and grants blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I used `terraform import` to link an aws_s3_bucket resources with the least parameters.
Since the bucket is in my state, it's allow me to reflect the real resource paramters (the first `terraform apply` failed, but it's intended).

I have some buckets with acl="private" which gave me errors and invite me to add some grants blocks. When i'm doing it, of course terraform gave me two ConflictWith errors since acl and grants cannont be used together.

But if for example i use a s3 bucket with the proper grants blocks, terraform invite me to add an acl="private" statement.

On the same time, I have a strange behavior with the force_destroy = false block. Which seems to be not detected.

Can somebody help me with me ? maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Code example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3-bucket-example" {
  bucket = "s3-bucket-example"
  force_destroy = false

  grant {
           permissions = [
               "READ",
               "READ_ACP",
               "WRITE",
            ] 
           type        = "Group" 
           uri         = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery" 
  }
  
  grant {
           id          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
           permissions = [
               "FULL_CONTROL",
            ] 
           type        = "CanonicalUser" 
  }
}
```

Result

```sh
# aws_s3_bucket.s3-bucket-jolivdi-acces will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3-bucket-example" {
      + acl                         = "private"
      + force_destroy               = false
        id                          = "s3-bucket-example"
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

Comment: Your real buckets that you import, have only `private acl`? They don't use any grants?

Comment: They used grants. This is why it's strange. It seems that they're using both :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely right and working fine.

[image]

I had checked the ACLs for the S3 bucket also. The permissions are perfectly applied as written in the terraform code.

If you still have any problems then please elaborate a bit in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! My code is OK (this is what i want at the end), but in my case it's the state linked to an existing object (with tf import) which generate some strange behavior

Comment: You can import the already created resource using terraform import command. eg. `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.s3-bucket-example BUCKET_NAME` This will import the S3 bucket with the current state.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue in aws provider version `3.63.0`, not sure which aws provider version you are using, but this seems to fixed only in `4.0.0` of aws provider [ref](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/22537).

There are 2 ways to fix this,

1. Go ahead and apply TWICE (this is what I did). After 1st apply, run plan again, the output will show as grants getting added though they are in state. Apply for 2nd time, there won't be drift further.
2. You may have to update the S3 bucket in state file directly to have current `acl` and `force_destroy` configuration, [instructions](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6193#issuecomment-847287379).